# Unit Test: How to mock Request that has route params in Lumen

Tags: laravel, api, phpunit, lumen

I created an API with Lumen and now I would create the test methods too. Okay, I know in TDD it could be the reversed way.

My API has an `init(Request $request)` method with an injected Request object. To test the working of course I have to create a mock Request. I do it like this:

```
$req = new Request([], [], ['param' => 'foo']);
```

It looks great, but the Request object has initialised as an empty object. I try to check the route param right after that:

```
dd($req->route('param'));
```

But it produces null; I spent hours to find out and googled for a solution, but I didn't find anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the third params from `\Illuminate\Http\Request` isn't the place you should pass the route params. If you take a look at that class, you'll find that the third params is custom attributes (I don't know exactly what it is).

To mock the request you could use method `create` from `\Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Ex. the route is `Route::post('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@store')`.

```php
$request = Request::create('/users/1', 'POST', [
    'name' => 'john doe',
]);

dd($request->route('user')); // 1
```

Here is the details:

```php
/**
 * Creates a Request based on a given URI and configuration.
 *
 * The information contained in the URI always take precedence
 * over the other information (server and parameters).
 *
 * @param string               $uri        The URI
 * @param string               $method     The HTTP method
 * @param array                $parameters The query (GET) or request (POST) parameters
 * @param array                $cookies    The request cookies ($_COOKIE)
 * @param array                $files      The request files ($_FILES)
 * @param array                $server     The server parameters ($_SERVER)
 * @param string|resource|null $content    The raw body data
 *
 * @return static
 */
public static function create($uri, $method = 'GET', $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks nmfzone. Now I have a route like:

    `Route::get('/{source}/{path:.*}', ['uses' => 'MyController@index']);`

With this i can get the first url segment in a 'source' and the other in a 'path' route parameters. And these parameters are what is missing from my $request object now.

Comment: @szatti1489 Btw, I've never seen route like that `/{path:.*}'`. Are you sure it's working?

Comment: Please update your question with your actual problem!! We just answer what you're questioning.